# Authenticating to external Active directory via Internet

Tags: exchange, active-directory

Is there any possibility to authenticate on Exchange server via external AD which could be reachable via Internet?

The whole story:

We have corporate Exchange server where all our users are working with email. However, we have our local domain with domain controller. So far, we didn't manage to interconnect them and it is better for us to have local domain under our management.

With this setup it means we have two logins. The first one is for our domain (shared folder security and other stuff) and the second one is for the corporate email which we have to use. My intention is to make Exchange server ask the server for usernames located in our domain and authenticate them. That would mean one password for one account and everyone will live a happy life. (imagine the mess in passwords when you have to change it every few months)

I'm not familiar with MS naming of these features, thus is very hard for me to find feature I'm looking for. If anybody could give me step by step solution, it would be really great.

Thank you in advance
Cheers!

Comment: The simplest method would be connect the client and the AD server to the same VPN

Comment: Active Directory Federation Services allows you to manage single sign on accross domains. You can also look at configuring a "Trust" between the two domains.

Comment: Lister: How much is that secure, if I have to "federate" two domains via internet? Does it use some sort of encryption or I have to use VPN tunnel?